# Line to points R

Tags: shapefile, r, points-to-line

I am trying to convert a polyline to a series of points.

My polyline is a simple shapefile.

So far I have used the command below which does a great job in converting my line to a bunch of points. However there are two major problems. First I have no control over the length between each point. I would like to have a point every five meter. Second I would like to give a unique ID to each of these points - which is not the case as for now.

```
point_line = as(coastal_line, "SpatialPointsDataFrame")
```

Comment: Would you consider using `sf` spatial classes? Then you can use `st_sample(LineFeature, N, type="regular")` to get N points regularly spaced on `LineFeature`. Compute `N` from the length of your line and your 5m separation.

Comment: @Spacedman my object is Formal class SpatialLines. When I use your code I get the following "Error in UseMethod("st_geometry") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_geometry' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialLines', 'Spatial', 'SpatialLinesNULL')""

Comment: because you've not converted your `sp` class object to `sf` class. Use `st_as_sf` and read up on `sp` and `sf` for more details.